# Perpendiculars from circumcenter of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Show that if perpendiculars are drawn from a point on the circum-circle of a triangle onto its sides then the feet are collinear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well know Simson line. You can see a solution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simson_line).

Comment: Thanks. (I was looking for a simpler proof using circle/triangle) properties)

Comment: My motivation was (not the result but) to fit in three points on differential   $r/\sin \psi  =$ diameter of a circle through origin to formulate it ... shall look it up.. thanks.